# How to solve the data overflow issue of the Fibonacci number for a large n?

Tags: c++, overflow, fibonacci

To clarify the overflow issue, I have the most simple code below to compute Fn with unsigned _int64 type:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned _int64 f0 = 0, f1 = 1, fn=1;
    for (unsigned n = 2; n < 101;n++ ) {
        fn = f1 + f0;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;        
        cout << "F" <<n<<" = "<< fn <<endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When n reaches 94, the output is incorrect as below:

```
F91 = 4660046610375530309
F92 = 7540113804746346429
F93 = 12200160415121876738
F94 = 1293530146158671551   (X)
F95 = 13493690561280548289
```

Comment: What is a "data overflow issue"? Why are you using `double` here? Fibonacci numbers are integers. Use `int64_t` or some kind of "bignum" if you need way longer numbers.

Comment: I don't think that long double is anywhere near being capable of representing fibonacci number indexed 1e7. Furthermore, for floating points the methods like `pow` compute several first significant digits. You don't seem to understand what you are doing.

Comment: The last five digits are all you care about, so why are you tracking the higher digits, that are causing the problem?

Comment: 1) Don't use floating point for integer calculations where you expect an exact result. 2) The last 5 digits of an integer `N` are `N % 100000`.

Comment: thanks for all comments. I just changed the codes in most simple way for Fn calculation only, with unsigned _int64 type, and show the overflow issue for F94.

Comment: @Lazer: C++ doesn't have a native type that holds more digits than `int64_t`. You'll need a bignum library.  Probably [boost::multiprecision::uint128_t](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

So, mathematics hit you hard. The problem is that the Fibonacci Series values are growing rapdily.

With [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) you can calculate that the maximum value that will fit in a 64 bit `unsigned long long` is already reached for the 94th Fibonacci number.

You need other approaches. For example this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t MaxDigits = 250'000u;

using Big = std::array<unsigned char, MaxDigits>;
std::array< Big, 3> f{};

int main() {

    size_t index = 100000u;

    std::array<size_t, 3> sf{};
    std::array<size_t, 3> indexF{ 0,1,2 };

    f[indexF[1]][0] = 1;
    sf[indexF[1]] = 1;
    size_t i{};

    unsigned char carry{};
    while (index--) {

        const size_t indexF0 = indexF[0];
        const size_t indexF1 = indexF[1];
        const size_t indexF2 = indexF[2];

        const size_t sf0 = sf[indexF0];
        const size_t sf1 = sf[indexF1];
        const size_t maxSize = std::max(sf0, sf1);

        for (i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i) {

            const unsigned char f0 = f[indexF0][i];
            const unsigned char f1 = f[indexF1][i];

            const unsigned char sum = carry + f0 + f1;

            (f[indexF2])[i] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        if (carry) {
            f[indexF2][i] = carry--;
            ++sf[indexF2];
        }
        else
            sf[indexF2] = maxSize;

        std::rotate(indexF.begin(), indexF.begin() + 1, indexF.end());
    }
    size_t count{};
    for (int k{ static_cast<int>(sf[indexF[0]]) - 1 }; k >= 0; --k) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>((f[indexF[0]])[k]);
        ++count;
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nNumber of digits: " << count << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, what we need is some "very big" data type. And here you could use a `std::vector` of digits. And as digit we will use an `unsigned char`.

For the following we will talk about "Digit" and "Digits" meaning an `unsigned char` and a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

For adding 2 Digits, we will use the method that we learned in school, when we were 7 years old. We add all single digits, and if there is an overflow over 10, we use it as "carry over" and add it the next time. That is rather simple.

Then we build an `operator +` for 2 "Digits", taking a little bit care about different number of elements in Digits and employ the simple "add" algorithm.

The example above calculates the 100'000th Fibonacci number. The time is somehow acceptable. It will produce a number wit 20899 digits. The solution is exact.

You could try also the 1'000'000th Fibonacci number, but this will take many minutes and produce a number with roundabout 209000 digits.

But for such big numbers you must use a BigInt library and you will get it done in some seconds

Happy calculating . . .